# How to specify or set a variable to a GPU device

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, multi-gpu, jax

I'm new to JAX and I want to work with multiple GPUs.
So far two GPUs (0 and 1) are visible to my JAX.

```
import jax
import os

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,1'
print(jax.local_devices())
>>>
# prints: [GpuDevice(id=0, process_index=0), GpuDevice(id=1, process_index=0)]
```

When I create a NumPy object it will always be in GPU device 0 which I assume is the default one.

```
nmp = jax.numpy.ones(4)
print(nmp.device())
>>>
# Prints: gpu:0
```

How can I send my variable `nmp` to be stored in `gpu:1`, the other GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.device_put()`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.device_put.html#jax.device_put)

```
import jax
import os

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,1'
devices = jax.local_devices()
print(devices) # >>> [GpuDevice(id=0, process_index=0), GpuDevice(id=1, process_index=0)]

nmp = jax.numpy.ones(4)
print(nmp.device()) # >>> gpu:0

nmp = jax.device_put(nmp, jax.devices()[1])
print(nmp.device()) # >>> gpu:1
```